Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') at HTMLButtonElement.submitEmail
So I recently deployed a newsletter sign-up form to my GitHub. I got the whole thing working in VS Code but when I tested it the link from GitHub pages, all of a sudden I get this TypeError in my console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') at HTMLButtonElement.submitEmail (script.js:36:36)
And on Firefox browsers the console logs this:
Uncaught TypeError: emailInputEl is null
So it's saying that the value is null but it's working properly in VS Code. Anyone have any idea why it might not be working? It's supposed to validate the user's email then take them to a thank you screen.
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Newsletter sign-up form with success message</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Sign-up form start -->
<main>
  <div class="subscribe-card">
      <div class="left-container">
          <h1 class="heading">Stay updated!</h1>
          <p class="description">Join 60,000+ product managers receiving monthly updates on:</p>
        <div class="list-wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li><p><span>Product discovery and building what matters</span></p></li>
            <li><p><span>Measuring to ensure updates are a success</span></p></li>
            <li><p><span>And much more!</span></p></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="sign-up-form">
          <div class="sign-up-container">
            <div class="labels">
              <label class="email-label" for="email-input" >Email address</label>
              <div class="error-label">Valid email required</div>
            </div>
            <input id="email-input" type="text" placeholder="email@company.com" required>
            <button class="subscribe-btn" type="submit">Subscribe to monthly newsletter</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="right-container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="375" height="284" viewBox="0 0 375 284"><defs><linearGradient id="b" x1="100%" x2="0%" y1="21.322%" y2="78.678%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF6A3A"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF527B"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="h" x1="22.319%" x2="99.127%" y1="28.497%" y2="70.858%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF3E83"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF9F2E"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="k" x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFB443"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF5B64" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="o" x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F8F8F8"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#EEE"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="p" x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#CACBE8"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#EEE"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#CACBE8"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="r" x1="97.791%" x2="7.729%" y1="26.944%" y2="71.879%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF9049"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF5E5E"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="t" x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF6A3D"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF5B66"/></linearGradient><path id="a" d="M0 0v268c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16h343c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16V0H0Z"/><path id="e" d="M0 14.054C0 6.292 6.292 0 14.054 0H220c7.762 0 14.054 6.292 14.054 14.054v128.108c0 7.762-6.292 14.054-14.054 14.054H14.054C6.292 156.216 0 149.924 0 142.162V14.054Z"/><path id="g" d="M0 5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 0H210.81a5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 5.946v128.108A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 210.81 140H5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 0 134.054V5.946Z"/><path id="i" d="M0 5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 0H210.81a5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 5.946v128.108A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 210.81 140H5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 0 134.054V5.946Z"/><path id="n" d="M0 5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 0h222.162a5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 5.946V129.73a5.946 5.946 0 0 1-5.946 5.946H5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 0 129.73V5.946Z"/><path id="q" d="M0 2.162C0 .968.968 0 2.162 0h48.649c1.194 0 2.162.968 2.162 2.162v65.946a2.162 2.162 0 0 1-2.162 2.162H2.162A2.162 2.162 0 0 1 0 68.108V2.162Z"/><filter id="d" width="151.3%" height="176.8%" x="-25.6%" y="-23%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"><feOffset dy="24" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/><feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="16"/><feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.100000001 0"/></filter><filter id="f" width="155.4%" height="185.7%" x="-27.7%" y="-25.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"><feOffset dy="24" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/><feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="16"/><feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.100000001 0"/></filter><filter id="j" width="155.4%" height="185.7%" x="-27.7%" y="-25.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"><feOffset dy="24" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/><feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="16"/><feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.100000001 0"/></filter><filter id="m" width="151.3%" height="188.4%" x="-25.6%" y="-26.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"><feOffset dy="24" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/><feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="16"/><feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.100000001 0"/></filter></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask id="c" fill="#fff"><use xlink:href="#a"/></mask><path d="M0 0v268c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16h343c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16V0H0Z"/><path fill="url(#b)" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M0 0v268c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16h343c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16V0H0Z" mask="url(#c)"/><g mask="url(#c)"><g fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(-16 87.784)"><use xlink:href="#e" fill="#000" filter="url(#d)"/><use xlink:href="#e" fill="#242742"/></g><g transform="translate(-7.351 95.892)"><g fill-rule="nonzero"><use xlink:href="#g" fill="#000" filter="url(#f)"/><use xlink:href="#g" fill="url(#h)"/></g><mask id="l" fill="#fff"><use xlink:href="#i"/></mask><g fill-rule="nonzero"><use xlink:href="#i" fill="#000" filter="url(#j)"/><use xlink:href="#i" fill="url(#h)"/></g><circle cx="210.81" cy="131.892" r="85.405" fill="url(#k)" fill-rule="nonzero" mask="url(#l)"/><circle cx="73.754" cy="-18.678" r="85.405" fill="url(#k)" fill-rule="nonzero" mask="url(#l)" transform="rotate(-135 73.754 -18.678)"/></g><g fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(157.513 35.892)"><use xlink:href="#n" fill="#000" filter="url(#m)"/><use xlink:href="#n" fill="url(#o)"/><path fill="url(#p)" d="M0 5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 0h45.946v135.676H5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 0 129.73V5.946Z"/><path fill="#BABBDB" d="M7.568 27.297c0-1.045.847-1.892 1.891-1.892h32.973a1.892 1.892 0 0 1 0 3.784H9.46a1.892 1.892 0 0 1-1.891-1.892Zm0 10.811c0-1.045.847-1.892 1.891-1.892h29.19a1.892 1.892 0 0 1 0 3.784H9.459a1.892 1.892 0 0 1-1.891-1.892Zm0 10.81c0-1.044.847-1.891 1.891-1.891h32.973a1.892 1.892 0 0 1 0 3.784H9.46a1.892 1.892 0 0 1-1.891-1.892Zm0 10.812c0-1.045.847-1.892 1.891-1.892h21.082a1.892 1.892 0 0 1 0 3.784H9.459a1.892 1.892 0 0 1-1.891-1.892Z"/><path fill="#242742" d="M0 5.946A5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 0h222.162a5.946 5.946 0 0 1 5.946 5.946v10.81H0V5.947Z"/><g transform="translate(8.649 4.865)"><circle cx="3.514" cy="3.514" r="3.514" fill="#FF6464"/><circle cx="15.406" cy="3.514" r="3.514" fill="#FF9255"/><circle cx="27.297" cy="3.514" r="3.514" fill="#6BD4A8"/></g></g><g transform="translate(220.757 24)"><path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M0 2.162C0 .968.968 0 2.162 0h48.649c1.194 0 2.162.968 2.162 2.162v65.946a2.162 2.162 0 0 1-2.162 2.162H2.162A2.162 2.162 0 0 1 0 68.108V2.162Z"/><mask id="s" fill="#fff"><use xlink:href="#q"/></mask><use xlink:href="#q" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero"/><path fill="url(#r)" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M58.444 15.61c.633.633.634 1.66 0 2.293l-13.662 13.67a6.018 6.018 0 0 1-8.512 0 2.774 2.774 0 0 0-3.925 0l-9.422 9.429a4.685 4.685 0 0 1-6.628 0 1.442 1.442 0 0 0-2.04 0L-3.178 58.444A1.622 1.622 0 1 1-5.47 56.15L11.96 38.709a4.685 4.685 0 0 1 6.629 0 1.442 1.442 0 0 0 2.04 0l9.422-9.428a6.018 6.018 0 0 1 8.513 0 2.774 2.774 0 0 0 3.924 0l13.663-13.67a1.622 1.622 0 0 1 2.293-.001Z" mask="url(#s)"/><path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M26.487 81.081c0-1.194.968-2.162 2.162-2.162h64.865c1.194 0 2.162.968 2.162 2.162v77.838a2.162 2.162 0 0 1-2.162 2.162H28.649a2.162 2.162 0 0 1-2.162-2.162V81.081Z"/><path fill="url(#t)" d="M25.135 42.703c9.702 0 17.568-7.866 17.568-17.568 0-9.702-7.866-17.567-17.568-17.567-9.702 0-17.567 7.865-17.567 17.567s7.865 17.568 17.567 17.568Zm0 7.567c13.882 0 25.135-11.253 25.135-25.135C50.27 11.253 39.017 0 25.135 0 11.253 0 0 11.253 0 25.135 0 39.017 11.253 50.27 25.135 50.27Z" transform="translate(36.217 94.595)"/><path fill="#242742" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M52.222 117.145c0 1.228.318 2.2.954 2.914.637.71 1.504 1.064 2.602 1.064 1.019 0 1.816-.363 2.39-1.09.58-.726.87-1.632.87-2.719h-.634c0 .62-.171 1.112-.515 1.478a1.688 1.688 0 0 1-1.284.55c-.546 0-.951-.184-1.216-.55-.264-.371-.397-.915-.397-1.63 0-.816.133-1.402.397-1.757.27-.36.67-.54 1.2-.54.568 0 1.01.234 1.326.7.315.468.473 1.304.473 2.51l.076.337c0 1.785-.392 3.052-1.174 3.8-.783.75-1.89 1.121-3.32 1.116h-.38v2.145h.44c2.297-.023 4.05-.645 5.261-1.867 1.216-1.227 1.825-2.88 1.825-4.957v-.44c0-1.869-.42-3.22-1.259-4.054-.839-.839-1.923-1.258-3.252-1.258-1.334 0-2.398.386-3.192 1.157s-1.191 1.802-1.191 3.091Zm14.764 8.26h2.61v-12.297h-2.442l-5.464 7.872v1.858h9.265v-2.103h-2.669l-.439.042h-3.514l2.61-4.088h.085v5.186l-.042.296v3.234Z"/></g></g></g></svg>
        <img class="desktop-image">
      </div>
  </div> 

  <!-- Success screen -->

  <div class="success-card hidden">
    <div class="thanks-container">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="check-container">
          <img class="checkmark-image">
        </div>
          <h1 class="heading">Thanks for subscribing!</h1>
          <p class="description">A confirmation email has been sent to <span class="email-address">ash@loremcompany.com</span>.
            Please open it and click the button inside to confirm your subscription.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a href="index.html">
            <button class="dismiss-btn" type="submit">
                Dismiss message
            </button>
          </div>
          </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
<script defer src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
  <footer>
    <div class="attribution">
      <p>Challenge by<a class="attribution-tag" href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">&nbsp Frontend Mentor</a></p>
      <p>&nbsp Coded by <a class="attribution-tag" href="https://www.treyjablinske.com/">&nbsp Trey Jablinske</a></p>
  </footer>
</html>

script.js
/* Create a function to navigates to the thank you page if the email address validation
 requirements are satisifed. So...

Click button -->
Check to see if email is valid -->
If email is VALID, then navigate to THANK YOU page -->
If email is INVALID, return error message to user to enter valid email and update CSS */

const subscribeCardEl = document.querySelector(".subscribe-card");
const successCardEl = document.querySelector(".success-card");

const emailInputEl = document.getElementById('email-input');
const errorElementEl = document.querySelector('.error-label');
const formEl = document.querySelector('.sign-up-form');
const submittedEmailEl = document.querySelector('.email-address');
const submitBtnEl = document.querySelector('.subscribe-btn');
const dismissBtnEl = document.querySelector('.dismiss-btn');

submitBtnEl.addEventListener("click", submitEmail);
dismissBtnEl.addEventListener("click", toggleCards);


function toggleCards() {
    subscribeCardEl.classList.toggle("hidden");
    successCardEl.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    return String(email).toLowerCase().match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}$/);
}

function submitEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Validate Email
    if (validateEmail(emailInputEl.value)) {
        submittedEmailEl.innerHTML = emailInputEl.value;
        toggleCards();
        emailInputEl.value = "";
        formEl.classList.remove('error');
    } else {
        formEl.classList.add('error');
    }
}


Sorry if this question has been answered before. I did a fair amount of research and searched these forums for answers before posting but I'm honestly stumped. Any help on this at all would be appreciated :) Thank you.

If you want to test this out on your browser, here's the link to the Github page. Couldn't put it in the question cause it was getting marked as spam: https://tjtbone95.github.io/Newsletter-Blog-Sign-Up/

document.getElementById('email-input') - That element exists in the code shown, but not in the code on the page linked.

Sounds like you didn't deploy your changes to the webserver.

Thanks for the comments guys. I was able to figure it out. For some reason, GitHub didn't upload my code correctly: the id fields on both my input tag and form tag weren't the same. I simply re-copied the code from my index.html in VS Code to my GitHub index.html and viola! The form submission works. Thanks for your help!
